# Vlookup formula is causing an error for certain cells

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have the `vlookup` formula below. I use the `Vlookup` since the range in the worksheet can shift and change. For some reason the "error" will display for certain cells with the formula. When I go into the formula (for the cells that show an error) everything except the brackets and cell references disappear.

```
(((A49,$A49:$AH212,34, ) ((A49,$AN51:$AR531,5, )))  ((A49,$A49:$AH212,34, )))
```

```
=IFERROR((VLOOKUP(A49,$A49:$AH212,34,FALSE)-(VLOOKUP(A49,$AN51:$AR531,5,FALSE)))/(VLOOKUP(A49,$A49:$AH212,34,FALSE)),"error")
```

It's troubling because the `vlookup` formula works perfect for the majority of cells. I do have quite a few macros and pivot tables. I'd think maybe that would have an impact on it but I am not sure.

Comment: Try those 3 vlookups in 3 different cells. And see what are they returning

Comment: Sounds like a display glitch. What version of Excel are you using? In any case, try putting the 3 lookups in separate (hidden?) helper columns; `=IFERROR((AA49-AB49)/AC49, "error")` is much easier to debug ;-)  ...that said I'd question the value of having an "error" string in place of an actual worksheet error that Excel and VBA code can understand as such. Magic string values are rarely a good idea.

Comment: Actually that would be `=IFERROR((AA49-AB49)/AA49, "error")`, or simpler still `=IFERROR(1-AB49/AA49, "error")`

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP yields `#N/A` when the lookup value can't be found in the left-most column of the lookup table: confirm that the lookup value exists. Watch for numbers formatted as text and leading/trailing spaces - make sure the expected match in the lookup table is identical, and avoid "format as text" whenever possible.

Use the "Evaluate formula" button in the "Formula" Ribbon tab to diagnose the formula, or break it down into helper columns:

```
[AA49]=VLOOKUP(A49,$A49:$AH212,34,FALSE)
[AB49]=VLOOKUP(A49,$AN51:$AR531,5,FALSE)
```

Now your formula can be simplified to `=IFERROR(1-AB49/AA49,"error")`, and the 2nd lookup no longer needs to be calculated twice for every row.

Looks like a "gross margin percent" calculation: `(retail-cost)/retail`, which is equivalent to `retail/retail-cost/retail`, i.e. `1-cost/retail`.

If the contents of the lookup table tends to change often, consider using `INDEX+MATCH` instead of `VLOOKUP`, especially if you're not using an Office 365 build; *any* cell change in the lookup table between A and AH (or between AN and AR) will cause a recalculation of the referencing lookup formula; this does not happen using `INDEX+MATCH` (it shouldn't happen with the latest Office 365 build either though).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I do not have the most recent office. Could you help me with making the index+Match for this case. Do you need more info?

Comment: @Tmacjoshua `VLOOKUP(A49,$A49:$AH212,34,FALSE)` would become `INDEX($AH49:$AH212,MATCH(A49,$A49:$A212,0))`, i.e. `index({where you pull the result from}, match({lookup value}, {where you find the lookup value}, 0))`